# Use an icon in a binary file as image in hta

Tags: dll, icons, hta

Is there a way to use an icon in a binary file (DLL for example) as an image in an HTA? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<img src="mydllfile.dll,2" width="32" height="32" border="0"/>
```